# Auto-expand embedded Youtube video on play

Tags: ajax, layout, video, youtube

***How do I automatically expand an embedded youtube video when the user presses play?***

**The situation:**
- For various reasons the ideal layout of the webpage mans that the video player must appear initially at a small size (let's say 480x385) when the user arrives on the page
- The video being shown contains some detail and is difficult to watch at 480x385
- Right now the user must click on the "full-screen" icon which comes standard in every youtube video player. This is irritating to many people.

**The desired solution:**
- When users click on the video to play it, the player automatically expands to a more reasonable size (e.g., 640x385 or 853x505) and plays at that size
- The video could be played in a modal overlay, but other solutions would be welcome as well
- Upon completion of the video, the expanded view should automatically disappear and the video should appear in it's original size on the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically need two things:

1. The ability to detect when the the video is playing.  You should be able to figure that out from [this YouTube example](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?exp=youtube#polling_the_player).
2. Resize the player by changing the height and width properties of the "object" node that contains the player.

Comment: mjhm: Thanks. Any suggestions on where to find good examples / guides on your #2?

Comment: Simple JavaScript.  Similar to this http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_img_height  but applied to the "object" element rather than the "img" element.